# Get network IP-address of the host computer

Tags: java, android, networking, localhost

I have a small home network, and I'd like to figure out  IP-address of the host computer within java (Android) app. There are many advices in the Internet, including Stackoverflow.com, but all advised ways give me 127.0.0.1, in fact IP-adresses in my network are like 192.168.1.x. I know that 127.0.0.x are local addresses within this device, whereas 192.168.1.x are IP within local network. Most advised way is `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()`, but it also gives 127.0.0.1. Class `NetworkInterface` was tried too, with the same result.

Any idea will be appreciated,
thanks in advance

PS I've found small program [find-local-devices.jar](https://cs.stanford.edu/people/nick/find-local-devices/), and it works perfectly, giving what I need (192.168.1.x), but there is no source code.

Comment: If you ran `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress()` of course that gives you `127.0.0.1`. That is the localhost of the Android device.

Comment: You could ping everything. You already know your subnet. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7218616/2308683

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get IP address of the device from code?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6064510/5221149)

Comment: cricket_007, thanks for a quick reply.  Of course, I know my subnet for now, but I'm not sure that this 192.168.1.x remains in future.